# I mess up installing my Ubuntu and now i can't boot my windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot

I almost know nothing about Ubuntu,my friends installed it for me (he is far away and can't be contacted so i can't ask for his help)

So it begin when i try to uninstall Ubuntu i delete the partition, put the memory Ubuntu used back to windows, and when i try to use windows repair tool some accident happen and power went down without me ever finishing making recovery media.

I search many forum how to deal with it, most suggest Windows Recovery(which i haven't finished yet), using Ubuntu disc thingy (which i also don't have)

I can't use command line 'is' for some reason even though many tutorial and answer suggest that so i can recognised windows

Long story short, can i still salvage my PC or should i just give up on it

Comment: Your best bet will be to use your Ubuntu LiveCD to salvage your files and restore your Windows installation - if you haven't got a Windows recovery from when you first purchased yoru computer then you'll need to purchase them from your computer manufacturer and take it as an expensive lesson in the importance of making recovery media the moment you open the computer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you uninstalled Ubuntu by deleting the partition you probably removed the GRUB bootloader, (The part where you could select your OS when booting).

You could try to fix your bootloader by borrowing (or [creating](http://www.howtogeek.com/186775/how-to-download-windows-7-8-and-8.1-installation-media-legally/)) a Windows install USB or DVD. On the media exists recovery tools which can repair such problems.

Alternatively, you could just create a new Bootable Linux USB or CD to re-install GRUB or just fix your bootloader. Furthermore, once you get back into Windows you can use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) in order to configure your bootloader properly. (Use with Caution!)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will be sure to remember that